# Overflow exception is throwing- even the value exceeds the limit

Tags: c#, exception, overflow, long-integer

Why the following code Gives output as `-2` instead for throwing `overflow exception`?

```
 long x = long.MaxValue;
 long y = long.MaxValue + x;
```

Comment: If you are going to force your application to throw overflow exception on all cases, go to your project "Properties ->  Build -> Advanced Built Setting" and check "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual behaviour depends on project settings, `unchecked` etc. To *ensure* overflow exception use `checked`, e.g.

```
 checked {
   long x = long.MaxValue;
   long y = long.MaxValue + x;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Presumably because you're executing it in an *unchecked* context. Arithmetic on the primitive integer types can execute in a [checked or unchecked context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx). Operations which overflow throw an exception in a checked context, and just use the bottom N bits (depending on the type) in an unchecked context. The default depends on the project settings, but the "default default" is unchecked.

You can either *explicitly* perform the operation in a checked context, or change the project settings.

Doing it explicitly (just for the arithmetic):

```
long x = long.MaxValue;
long y = checked(long.MaxValue + x);
```

Note that constant expressions are checked at compile time, and overflow will result in a compile-time error unless it's *explicitly* unchecked (regardless of project settings). For example:

```
long x = long.MaxValue + 1; // Error
long y = unchecked(long.MaxValue + 1); // Equivalent to y = long.MinValue
```