# Why -2? Why not -3 or -1?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = Int32.MaxValue;
        int b = Int32.MaxValue;             

        Console.WriteLine(a+b);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: -2

Overflow occurs but how does it calculate and find -2 as a result?

Comment: Why do you prefer -3 or -1?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think its just a generic question how the runtime comes up with -2 as result

Comment: @TimSchmelter I dont prefer anything over other but it seems odd that it directly finds -2 as a result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201811/overflow-exception-is-throwing-even-the-value-exceeds-the-limit may give some information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the same number to itself, so I would at least expect the sum to be an even number. (odd + odd = even)
But why -2?

The number line is a circle:

```
     -1    0
-2            1
...              ...
...              ...
...              ...
   -2147483648 2147483647
```

Adding 1 to a number is in effect taking one step clockwise on this circle.
Adding 1 to 2147483647 (=int.MaxValue) takes you to -2147483648 (=int.MinValue)

If you start at 2147483647 and take 2147483647 steps on the circle, you end up at -2.

What's funny about this: we say overflow occurs at int.MaxValue => int.MinValue, and in decimal notation it does, but in binary notation, the overflow occurs at -1 (all 1's) => 0 (all 0's), on the opposite side of the circle.

Answer (score 9):

Write it down as binary strings:

```
 0111 1111 1111 1111
+0111 1111 1111 1111
--------------------
 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

And the latter is exactly -2. This is because the first digit is -2^31 instead of 2^31. Therefore, the sum is -2^31 + 2^30 + 2^29 + ... + 2^2 + 2^1 = -2

(In truth, Int32 has 32 binary digits and not just 16)

Comment: @Georg why latter is -2? 1st bit shows the sign? You mean this?

Comment: @Lyrk Updated my answer. The first bit does not show the sign but simply represents -2^31

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you `overflow` `Int32.MaxValue` like `Int32.MaxValue+count` the value will become `Int32.MinValue+x`. Where `x = count-1`

So `Int32.MaxValue+1 = -2147483648`

`-2147483648 + Int32.MaxValue-1 = -2`

So in your case it is `-2147483648+(2147483647-1)` which is `-2`