# How is the integer value determined when the assigned value is larger than the int max value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

We have an instance where a value being assigned to an integer is larger than the int max value (2,147,483,647). It doesn't throw an error, it just assigns a smaller number to the integer. How is this number calculated?

This has been fixed by changing the int to a long but I'm interested as to how the smaller value is being calculated and assigned to the int.

Comment: int.MaxValue + 1 == int.MinValue

Comment: `Int16.MaxValue OR Int32.MaxValue OR Int64.MaxValue`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098378/why-2-why-not-3-or-1/33098714#33098714

Comment: The search term you're looking for is _integer overflow_.

Answer (score 3):

int contains a 32-bit number which means, it has 32 binary digits of 0 or 1 (first digit means plus for 0 and minus for 1), for example:

```
1 in decimal  == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 as int32 binary
2 147 483 647 == 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

So, if you'll increment `int.MaxValue`, you will get next result:

```
2 147 483 648 == 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation this binary number equals to `int.MinValue` or `-2 147 483 648`

Answer (score 0):

```
int.MaxValue:    2,147,483,647
```

The logic in loops is keeping track of the lowest number found. You can use int.MaxValue to start the value really high, and then any lower number will be valid.

Sample code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
int[] integerArray = new int[]
{
    10000,
    600,
    1,
    5,
    7,
    3,
    1492
};

// This will track the lowest number found
int lowestFound = int.MaxValue;

foreach (int i in integerArray)
{
    // By using int.MaxValue as the initial value,
    // this check will usually succeed.
    if (lowestFound > i)
    {
    lowestFound = i;
    Console.WriteLine(lowestFound);
    }
}
}
}
```

Output

```
10000
600
1
```